# Reading lines from files without storing anything wastes memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

I have a folder with 2000 folders in it (0001 to 2000), each of which contains a number of files, with a total of 145000 files in the original folder.
I read each folder and then read each file in folder. For each file I read it line by line and do some storing and processing. But the memory usage is terrible. I thought the problem was with storing, but when I cleaned the code (storing and processing), I see that even without storing something, the memory usage is as same as before. Total size of my files is 3.6 GB. After executing the code for half of folders (approx. 1.8GB), it takes 5GB of main memory. What is wrong with this code?
The code is here:

```
#define  LINE_BUFFER_LEN        40960
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    DIR *dpdf;
    struct dirent *epdf;
    string fcount;
    string path="/media/modb/78E60A4AE60A0958/final/"; 
    string filename, filenumber;
    int filenum;
    char buffer[LINE_BUFFER_LEN];
    string readFilePath;
    ifstream infile;

    int folderCount=1;
    int periodFilesCount=0;
    while (folderCount<2001){
        fcount=IntToString(folderCount);
        numOfzeros=(4-fcount.size());
        fcount.insert(fcount.begin(), numOfzeros, '0');
        dpdf = opendir((path+fcount).c_str());
        if (dpdf != NULL){
           while (epdf = readdir(dpdf)){
               if (epdf->d_type==8){
                    filename=string(epdf->d_name);
                    filename=(filename.substr(0,filename.size()-4));

                    filenumber=(filename.substr(filename.find('_')+1,filename.size()));
                    filenum=atoi(filenumber.c_str());

                    readFilePath=path+fcount+"/"+filename+".txt";
                    infile.open(readFilePath.c_str());

                    if(!infile) {
                            cout<<"Error\n";
                    }
                    while(infile.getline(buffer, LINE_BUFFER_LEN))
                    {
                        //The code cleaned from here.
                        loopCounter++;
                    }
                    infile.close();
                    cout<<endl;
               }
           }
        }
        closedir(dpdf);
        folderCount++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage?

Comment: in Linux with free -m. That is to say for the entire files, it fails with segmentation fault.

Comment: So, basically you are complaining that Linux is using "free" memory to cache your files....

Comment: I suggest that you measure your program's memory usage with something like `ps`, `top` or the contents of `/proc/[pid]/status`.

Comment: OK! got it. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Could be just page cache filling up, which is not a problem.